# Parallel.ForEach losing data

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

Parallel.ForEach helps improve performance however, I am seeing data loss.

Tried - variables results, processedData are `ConcurrentBag<IwrRows>`

1)

```
Parallel.ForEach(results, () => new ConcurrentBag<IwrRows>(), (n, loopState, localData)    =>
{
 return ProcessData(n); // ProcessData complicated business logic
}, (localData) => AddRows(localData, processedData, obj)
);
```

2)

```
await Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(results, item =>
        {
            ProcessData(item, processedData);  
        }));
```

3)

```
Parallel.ForEach(results, item =>
 {
 ProcessData(item, processedData);
 });
```

All of them lost some rows.

When I use the foreach block it returns consistently the same value however, its 4 times slower.

```
foreach (var item in results)
        {
            // ProcessData returns a List<IwrRows>
            processedData.AddRange(ProcessData(item));
        }
```

Not sure what I am missing here.

results - 51112
Foreach returns 41316 rows back.
ForeachParallel returns 41308 or 41313 or 41314 varies with each run

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: What is the definition of `ProcessData()`?

Comment: I agree with one point in makro88's answer: You should at least explain what is the usual expected return value of the ProcessData() function so others can better help you out. As your question is written right now, it seems that this function returns a collection of processed data, containing 0-N items. Could you please EDIT the question and clarify this point? The expected math of number of items is not clear and not reproducible by others. Try to isolate your issue in a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as mentioned before, otherwise this question is should be flagged and closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Is Parallel.ForEach in ConcurrentBag<T> thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629935/is-parallel-foreach-in-concurrentbagt-thread-safe)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to struggle with the results and getting them back into a coherent list. You could use PLinQ, so you don't have to bother with the results container being thread-safe:

```
var processedData = yourData.AsParallel().Select(ProcessData).ToList();
```

Comment: This returns consistently the same rows of data when compared with the foreach loop. Its twice as slow as Parallel.Foreach but faster than the foreach. What is the difference between Parallel.Foreach and AsParallel in this scenario? Why even after using ConcurrentBag I was losing data?

Answer (score 5):

You problem seems to be in: AddRows(localData, processedData, obj). This method is probably adding data to a list which is not thread safe. You should add the to a thread safe list or make some synchronizing around the adding of the data.

Comment: Actually, the OP mentioned `processedData` is of type `ConcurrentBag<IwrRows>`, which should, in theory, handle the concurrency issue.

Answer (score 0):

using `await Task.Run` in 2) is useless i think.

If `Foreach returns 41316 rows back` for `Results - 51112`
than problem is not in `Parallel.ForEach` but in your adding / processing mechanism. Remember that even if `ConcurrentBag` guarantees that each operation on it is thread-safe, it doesn't take care of duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Well there might be definitely problem with your buisness logic (ProcessData).
Maybe not a pararell.foreach but I think this one might speed up a little your code, it's async as well using LINQ.
Thats the way, I'm handling Parallel async operations on some data.
You'll probably need to flatten the result of taskList (its full pseudo-code written from head).  You could always use yield return always to materialize later your list, that might fasten it a bit more. But use yield with caution :)

```
var taskList = results.Select(async item =>
    {
        return await ProcessData(item, processedData);  
    });

await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
```

Use WhenAll or WaitAll depend on the case you want

> Task.WaitAll:

```
At least one of the Task instances was canceled -or- an exception was thrown during the execution of  
at least one of the Task instances.If a task was canceled, the AggregateException contains an  
OperationCanceledException in its InnerExceptions collection.
```

Task.WhenAll:

```
If any of the supplied tasks completes in a faulted state, the returned task will also complete in a   
Faulted state, where its exceptions will contain the aggregation of the set of unwrapped exceptions  
from each of the supplied tasks.
```